# WooCommerce coupons - how to apply percentage coupon THEN store credit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

Currently, using the WooCommerce Smart Coupons plugin, when combining two different coupons, a store credit is used first and then a percentage is used on the total after the first coupon is used.

This is illogical when you give someone store credit and they want to take that amount off of the cart total AFTER using the full % off. I'd like for this to work the opposite - use the percentage off coupon, then the store credit.

To be clear: The way it works now is...

- Cart subtotal = $100
- $10 Store credit coupon = -$10
- 10% off coupon = -$9
- Cart total = $81

The way it SHOULD work is...

- Cart subtotal = $100
- $10 Store credit coupon = -$10
- 10% off coupon = -$10
- Cart total = $80

Does anyone else have this issue? If so, how can it be fixed? Thanks!

EDIT 1: I've narrowed down this issue to being with the Smart Coupons plugin after disabling it and the calculations working as they should once disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to UNCHECK a line item in the Woocommerce settings under the "General" tab and "Enable Coupons" section that says "Calculate coupon discounts sequentially"